# How to check if background video has loaded?

Tags: video, background, loaded, imagesloaded

Hoping you can help. I am wondering if its possible to check if a background video has loaded?

In the past I have used [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) to check if a background image has loaded but I was hoping I could do similar for a background video?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking at a HTML5 implementation, the HTML5 video tag supports a callback for video loaded:

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myBackgroundVideoID");
myVideo.onloadeddata = function() {
    //Do whatever you  want when video is loaded here
};
```